# Getting strings for Ruby templates?

Tags: ruby, templates, erb

In the below script the `puts` outputs

```
admin1:secretpw@example.com
```

where I need to have it split in a username and a password, so I can use it for a template

```
[admins]
<%= couchdbAdminUri.user %> = <%= couchdbAdminUri.password %>
```

**Question**

How can I turn `couchdbAdminUri` into an object so I can use the template above?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'erb'
require 'yaml'
require 'uri'
require 'awesome_print'

data_root = '/vol'
config_root = File.join(data_root, 'config')

couchdb = YAML::load_file(File.join(config_root, 'couchdb.yaml'))
couchdbAdminUri = URI(couchdb['_admin']['db'])

puts couchdbAdminUri

b = binding
tmp = ERB.new File.read("local.ini.erb"), nil, "%"
File.open("local.ini", "w") do |f|
  f.write(tmp.result(b))
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a class

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'erb'
require 'yaml'
require 'uri'
require 'awesome_print'

data_root = '/vol'
config_root = File.join(data_root, 'config')

couchdb = YAML::load_file(File.join(config_root, 'couchdb.yaml'))
result = URI(couchdb['_admin']['db']).split(':')

class CredentialURI
  attr_reader :user, :password
  def initialize(user, pwd)
     @user = user
     @password = pwd
  end
end

user = result.first
password = result.last

couchdbAdminUri = CredentialUri.new(user, password)

b = binding
tmp = ERB.new File.read("local.ini.erb"), nil, "%"
File.open("local.ini", "w") do |f|
  f.write(tmp.result(b))
end
```